# vsftpd: Multiple FTP users along with a master user

Tags: vsftpd

### Scenario

1. Multiple FTP users *user1*, *user2* etc those can both SSH and do FTP with homedir /home/user1, /home/user2 respectively.
2. A *master* FTP user who have access to all other FTP account.
3. Files uploaded by user *master* can be managed (view, delete, modify etc) by *userX*
4. Files uploaded by *userX* can be managed by user *master*
5. *user1* should not be able to access files of *user2*

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in the following way:

```
useradd master
passwd master
chmod 700 /home/master

useradd -G master user1
passwd user1
usermod -a -G user1 master
chmod 770 /home/user1

useradd -G master user2
passwd user2
usermod -a -G user2 master
chmod 770 /home/user2
```

The vsftpd.conf need to be tweaked as following:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=007
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
```

Explanation

- *userX* is a member of group *master*, so files uploaded by user *master* can be managed by *userX*.
- User *master* is a member of group *userX*, so files uploaded by *userX* can be managed by user *master*
- g=rwx permission for homedir, so user *master* have access to all user homedirs.